# Why an enum instance is not released from memory after being used

Tags: .net, memory

I see that there is an object in memory into CustomControl namespace:

"WpfApplication66.CustomControl.LayoutChanged[]"
even though it was closed. Because?

[image]

Comment: That's not an enum instance. That's an array. We can't really tell much more than that - do you have a static variable anywhere?

Comment: Because something still holds a reference to the array?  Because the form was closed but something holds a reference to the form?  Because GC hasn't run and there's no memory pressure to force it to?  What problems is this causing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The type name `LayoutChanged[]` refers to an array, not an enum. This is important, because arrays are usually subject to garbage collection.
2. For an object to become *eligible* for GC in .NET, it has to be definitely unreachable from a set of roots (such as thread stack frames and global variables). It's not clear from the information you've provided that this is the case.
3. The .NET GC isn't deterministic, as far as user code is concerned. It will collect whenever the runtime thinks it needs to collect (which in some cases can simply be *never*). It's possible that the GC hadn't attempted to collect anything at the moment you took the profiler snapshot.
4. The .NET GC is generational, which means that it won't bother to collect all objects on every cycle - it may restrict itself to specific generations of objects. As objects survive collection cycles, they get promoted to an older generation, which gets collected less frequently.